# c# constructor get 'base' part with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor

I'm currently trying to parse public member of some random dll, i'm stuck in getting the base part of constructor with the reflection

```
public class MyClass: MySuperClass
 {
   public MyClass(Color color1, Color color2)
          : base(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, color1, color2)
        {
           //...
        }
  }
```

From the Type i figure it how to get the constuctor and the parameters but not the call to parent class constructor ': base(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, color1, color2)'

```
var MyType = typeof(MyClass);
foreach (ConstructorInfo MyConstructor in MyType.GetConstructors())
{
     var MyParameters = MyConstructor.GetParameters();

     //todo get base parameters ': base(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, color1, color2)' ? 
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to get the list of parameters/value used in the parent constructor call ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Reflection gets you the surface of classes. The base class call or in other cases the calll to other constructors ot the same class here is part of the implemented body of the constructor method. SO you would need to inspect the generated IL code to see if and how a different method was called.

Comment: You cannot do this without decompiling the CIL body. And please also note that not only base constructors can be called.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i will look into this way, see if i can get something

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going into the Type of `MyClass` you can go into the `BaseType` and check out the constructors of of the parent class:

```cs
Type mySuperClassType = typeof(MyClass).BaseType;
        foreach (ConstructorInfo MyConstructor in mySuperClassType.GetConstructors())
        {
            var MyParameters = MyConstructor.GetParameters();
            Console.WriteLine(MyConstructor.ToString());
            // prints Void .ctor(Single, Single, Single, Single, System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing.Color) 
        }
```

working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S7CFT0

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question